# How Does Firebase Analytics count New Users in Web App

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

We have a web app that users log into using Firebase Auth. According to our the authentication section of our firebase console, we have 690 user that have created accounts, and we believe that is correct.

According to our Firebase Analytics console, we have 2,100 new users in the past 90 days. I think I understand that Firebase Analytics tracks users with a device ID (?). So, if this were a iOS app, an uninstall and install would trigger a a new user counted in analytics. But, how does this work on a web app? Cookie? Some kind of browser id? A session?

So, I think if we want to track unique users accurately, we would use the set the user id, with this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.analytics.Analytics#setuserid

Which according to the docs linked above, 'Use gtag 'config' command to set 'user_id'. So it does this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id#set_user_id

Which allows the users to be tracked across sessions. Therefore, users should not double count.

Notice that the setUserId section in the firebase analytics docs does not have a web section (although the setUserID function does exist in the javascript sdk as shown tow links above) https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid

So... would it then work to get the user id (uid) when they log in (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User). And then use the setUserId method to set the id?

It's unclear because the documentation does not seem to be in one source. I am just trying to put it all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can use the setUserId API (across iOS, web and Android) in order to identify the same user across platforms. Note that you'll need to:

1. Set the default reporting identity to "By User-ID then Device" in the Reporting settings for Google Analytics in the Firebase console (see attached screenshot and [docs for more](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) info).
2. Make sure you are following the [Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy) when using the User ID.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will do this and then...I wonder if I should wipe out ( if I can) all previous analytics data, so that I can start with a correct user count.